# Html/CSS (Only) DatePicker

Tags: css, html, angular, ng-bootstrap

Is There Any Good **DatePickers** Built using Bootstrap or HTMl/CSS
i am already using this one https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples
but its not working out for me

Comment: show us what you tried so far

Comment: i am using angular,html/css and bootstrap on front end " have tried different date pickers libraries of angular and bootstrap as i mentioned above a link that i used its working fine but with improper styling this is beacause i havent included the bootstrap cdn but when i do the whole app styling breaks

Comment: `but its not working out for me` that the reason why i ask you to show code it not help to find something else show your one and your issuse and we try to help you solve the issuse

Comment: there is no error in the console , as i said before if i include the bootstrap library the whole app styling breaks because of the css collision.please tell me if there is any good way of including datepicker only using html and css

Answer (score 5):

There is this:

```
<input type="date" />
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button"  (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle selector calendarSelector"
          style="margin-left:-1" [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" aria-controls="collapseExample">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar calendarIcon"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span>
        </button>
        <div id="collapseExample" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed"  class="dropdown-menu ">
          <ngb-datepicker  #d1 style="padding:30px; font-size: 11px !important;border:none;line-height: 1px;
          letter-spacing: 1px;" (click)='searchArticleByDate();isCollapsed = !isCollapsed ' [(ngModel)]="model1" name="something" #c1="ngModel"></ngb-datepicker>
        </div>


      </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

for Jquery use jquery ui Datepicker:

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

for Angularjs use Bootstrap ui date picker:

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker